# ViewPagerAndroid doesnt show children

Tags: react-native

I copied straight from the documentation here:

```
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                Welcome to React Native!
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                To get started, edit App.js
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                {instructions}
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.main}>
                <ViewPagerAndroid style={styles.viewPager} initialPage={0}>
                    <View style={styles.pageStyle}>
                        <Text>First page</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.pageStyle}>
                        <Text>Second page</Text>
                    </View>
                </ViewPagerAndroid>
            </View>
        </View>
```

And my stylesheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
    main: {
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        height: 300
    },
    viewPager: {
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
    },
    pageStyle: {
        padding: 20,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

All is the `pink` and `skyblue` rectangles. I have no idea why the child is not rendering. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I ran your code and I can see green pages in the view pager with text 'First Page' and 'Second Page'

Comment: Thanks @AnkitAggarwal - this is so weird. Which version of RN are you using? Does `peekEnabled` work for you?

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal I updated my code with my actual code may you please try that? It seems to not work when wrapped in a `View` that is `flex:1`

Comment: I am using "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6" and "react-native": "0.44.0". I copied the code you updated, it was not showing anything on the screen. Then I added width in style.main and it worked. I can see both the pages in the view pager. I hope you are running it on Android and not on iOS because ViewPagerAndroid component is only for android. I don't see any reason why it will not work.

Comment: Very interesting thanks @AnkitAggarwal! I will try the widge trick.